# Nav-bar Foundation Become Down Position

Tags: zurb-foundation, navbar

I have problem using nav-bar menu on foundation 3. I use default code on foundation 3 old doc but the menu become down. Please see my attach. [https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/4178068/487263/0e3ed49a-b951-11e2-9e10-ce74723ef6b3.jpg]
Please help regarding my problem. Thank you.

Some code:

```
<ul class="nav-bar">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The items on your nav-bar are exceeding the width of your template. You have to either give a bigger width to the `.row` class located in the `foundation.css` or remove some items from the nav-bar.

Comment: Thanks Billy but another idea ?? My row is can not modify again because client request and nav-bar too.

Comment: You could decrease the `font-size` of the `nav-bar` items so they occupy less space.. I can not figure out something else.. There is no magical way to fit something that is 100px to a 50px space.

Comment: But my client want the layout as this https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/4178068/487263/0e3ed49a-b951-11e2-9e10-ce74723ef6b3.jpg. But as web testing part, the menu become down. Would you please help with another way without change layout (font, decrease menu text, increase row, etc)? Thank you